# What does mean "both" in this sentence?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Ruby has two forms of multiple-selection constructs, **both** of which are
>   called case expressions and **both** of which yield the value of the last expression evaluated.

what ***both*** refers to?

Comment: "Both" refers to the "two forms of multiple-selection constructs".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following sentences:

1. Raj has two balls, both of which are red.
2. Raj has two balls of equal size, both of which are red in colour.

There are two balls about which the sentence after comma describes.

So "both" in your sentence describes about the 'two forms'.

Here 'both' is used as a pronoun which refers two things together. In this case the two forms. And both always mentions two things and not multiple things or so.

Comment: so with your answer you say that; it means that one of two forms is called case exp. and other form is that yield the value of the last exp. evaluated ***or*** each of forms are called case exp. and will yield the value of the last exp. evaluated ?

Comment: No pal. Both the forms are called CaseExpressions and they both yield the value of the last expression evaluated it seems. I don't know about ruby. Just check with some examples in ruby.

Comment: Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Both is an indefinite pronoun replacing in Ruby’s case the noun: “form of multiple-selection constructs” and in Raj’s case the noun: “ball”.
Both is the dual (plural) form of an indefinite pronoun.